# Javascript Input function not working and global variable

Tags: javascript, webstorm

`window.prompt` is giving me "window not defined" error.. I'm trying to get user input with a function and use the value for another line of code.

How do I get user input what are all the ways I can do this efficiently?

```js
var mYval = null;

function myfn() {
  mYval = window.prompt("Enter your name: ");
  alert("Your name is " + name);
  return mYval
}
myfn();
```

Error I'm getting :

> var mYval = window. prompt("Enter your name: "); alert("Your name is " + name);   ^ ReferenceError: window is not defined –

Comment: Please limit your questions on StackOverflow to one specific problem. Where are you running your code in the first question; in a browser or somewhere else (eg Node)? What exactly does the error message say?

Comment: `let add = null; function math() { add = prompt('whatever') } math(); console.log(add)`

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _"running the code in webstorm"_? Are you directly running a JS script or is it in a webpage?

Comment: Updated the question kindly check!

Comment: I'm writing code in webstorm and using run function. The terminal shows the output. I need to see how working with code and browser works after solving few problems first. Now I'm in webstorm IDE and using run function to show output in terminal of webstorm.

Comment: Your code is invalid. It produces _"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'var'"_ because `mYval var mYval =` is incorrect

Comment: Question updated again.. I tried both "var mYval =" and "mYavl="  before using the window.prompt code.

Comment: *"I'm writing code in webstorm and using run function. The terminal shows the output."* This suggests that you are running it using **Node** (so it's CLI environment) and not a browser. `window` variable is not defined there. If you run your code via browser (for that you need to execute a HTML file that references your script) then it will work better (I'm referring to the " window is not defined " part)

Answer (score 0):

The variable you use to capture the value must be the same you use in the `alert`

```js
var mYval = null;

function myfn() {
  mYval = window.prompt("Enter your name: ");
  alert("Your name is " + mYval);   // <-- `mYval` was `name`
  return mYval
}
myfn();
```

If you're running from the console (e.g., via node) or in an IDE-emulator; the `window` object may not be available.  In that case you should reassess your runtime environment.